# Refactoring a multithreaded class into a single threaded + a multithreaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, refactoring

I have a multithreaded c++ class implemented in such way:

```
class MyClass{
protected:
  somemutex mutex; 
  void _unsafeMethod(){...};
public:
  void safeMethod{
    locker lock(mutex);
    _unsafeMethod();
  }
}
```

I'm happy with that, but noticed that in most occasions, the multithreading support isn't really necessary, so I'd love to split that into 2 classes: a thread safe one, and an unsafe, but more performing one.

The issue is, there are many thousands lines of code using the class, so I need to keep interface identical. Of course, the class name will change in its definitions, depending on whether it needs to support MT or not.

I had in mind something like the following:

**Solution A**

```
class MyClass{
protected:
  void _unsafeMethod(){...};
public:
  virtual void safeMethod{
    _unsafeMethod()
  };
};
class MyThreadSafeClass: public MyClass{
protected:
  somemutex mutex; 
public:
  virtual void safeMethod{
    locker lock(mutex);
    _unsafeMethod();
  };
}
```

The issue here are the virtual function calls: does it makes execution slower, so I immediately lose the benefit of the single thread class performance improvement? From the first test it looks like

**Solution B**

```
class MyClass{
protected:
  somemutex * pmutex;
  void _unsafeMethod(){...};
public:
  MyClass( bool isthreadsafe ){
    if( isthreadsafe )
       pmutex = new somemutex();
    else
       pmutex = NULL;
  };
  void safeMethod{
    if( pmutex )
    {
       locker lock(*pmutex);
       _unsafeMethod();
    }
    else
      _unsafeMethod();
  };
}
```

This second solution looks dirty, and there's always an 'if' in each call to be resolved.

Which solution you think is more efficient? Is there a better/cleaner/more performing solution you have on mind?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not pass the mutex as a parameter to the constructor? that way you can choose any number of locking mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a decorator pattern or wrapper. .

**A**]A modified  wrapper so that you get away with virtual functions:

```
class MyClass{
protected:
  void _unsafeMethod(){};

};

class MyThreadSafeClass{
protected:
  somemutex mutex; 
  MyClass& myclassRef;
public:
    MyThreadSafeClass(MyClass& myclass):myclassRef(myclass){}
  void safeMethod(){
    locker lock(mutex);
    myclassRef._unsafeMethod();
  }
};
```

Class invocation:

```
MyClass myclass;
MyThreadSafeClass mythreadsafeclass(myclass);
mythreadsafeclass.safeMethod();
```

**B**] A decorator with virtual interface:

```
class MyClassInterface{
public:
  virtual void Method()=0;

};

class MyClass : public MyClassInterface{
protected:
  virtual void Method() override{};

};

class MyThreadSafeClass: public MyClassInterface{
protected:
  somemutex mutex; 
  MyClassInterface& myclassRef;
public:
    MyThreadSafeClass(MyClassInterface& myclass):myclassRef(myclass){}
   virtual void Method() override{
     locker lock(mutex);
     myclassRef.Method();
  }
};
```

Comment: And where are the virtual functions? o.o

Comment: Do not need. The client would just use `MyThreadSafeClass` decorator class when dealing with multithreading. The `_unsafeMethod` can be made public if the `MyClass` is to be used by single thread.

Comment: The O.P is concerned about execution speed and virtual may slow down things a little though not much.

Comment: Thanks! I'm implementing an approach much similar to this!

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward answer would be to template `MyClass` on a mutex type:

```
template <typename MutexType>
class MyClass{
protected:
  MutextType mutex; 
public:
  void safeMethod{
    locker lock(mutex);
    // stuff
  }
}
```

Then you either instantiate it with a real mutex or a no-op mutex to get the behavior you desire.

Comment: Great approach I did not think off, just not viable becuase my class is HUGE, and can't move it in a .h

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the mutex as a parameter to the constructor. This will allow you to select the locking mechanism without having to modify or duplicate the implementation for each locking type you wish to you.

```
class Mutex
{
public:
    virtual void Lock() = 0;
};

class MyClass
{
protected:
    Mutex&   mutex;

public:

    MyClass(Mutex& m) : mutex(m) {}

    void Lock()
    {
        mutex.Lock();
    }
};
```